# Loading images in galleryview

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

I want to load images in gallery view in a manner that once images is load than after when user scrolls, want to show loading indicator and than after new image will be display.
    in my below code it takes all the data(including images) and display.

here is my code:

ProductDetailsActivity.java

```
public class ProductsDetailActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
    Gallery gallery;
    TextView prod_descri, productTitle1, productTitle2;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    ImageView leftArrow, rightArrow;
    private int selectedImagePosition = 0;
    private List<Drawable> drawables;
    String title, url, title1;
    Bundle b;
    Products product;
    ProductDetails pDetails;
    ArrayList<ProductDetails> productList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.products_details);
        init();

        setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_product));
        b = getIntent().getExtras();
        product = (Products) b.getSerializable("product");
        if (b != null) {
            if (Global.isNetworkAvailable(ProductsDetailActivity.this)) {
                new ProductAsyncTask().execute(Constants.url,
                        product.product_id);
            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ProductsDetailActivity.this,
                        OfflineActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            Log.v("Bundle", "Bundle null");
        }

    }
    private void init() {
        productList = new ArrayList<ProductDetails>();
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.product_gallery);
        prod_descri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
        productTitle1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productTitle1);
        productTitle2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productTitle2);
        leftArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_imageview);
        rightArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow_imageview);
        leftArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        rightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.left_arrow_imageview:

            if (selectedImagePosition > 0) {

                // leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                --selectedImagePosition;
            } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {
                leftArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);

            break;
        case R.id.right_arrow_imageview:
            if (selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {
                // rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ++selectedImagePosition;
            } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {
                rightArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        selectedImagePosition = position;

        productTitle1.setText(product.title);
        productTitle2.setText(product.title);
        prod_descri.setText(product.long_description);

        if (selectedImagePosition > 0
                && selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {
            leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0 && drawables.size() > 1) {
            leftArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1
                && drawables.size() > 1) {
            rightArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (drawables.size() == 1) {
            rightArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            leftArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        // setSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

    // AsyncTask

    public class ProductAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<ProductDetails>> {

        private Context getDialogContext() {
            Context context;
            if (getParent() != null)
                context = getParent();
            else
                context = ProductsDetailActivity.this;
            return context;
        }

        String responseString = null;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public ProductAsyncTask() {
            super();
            // progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductsDetailActivity.this);
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getDialogContext());
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ProductDetails> doInBackground(String... params) {

            responseString = readJSONSFeed(params[0], params[1]);

            if (responseString != null) {
                    return processProductDetailsJSON(responseString);
            } else {

                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ProductDetails> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (result.size() == 0 || result == null) {

                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                drawables = createDrawables(result);
                imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ProductsDetailActivity.this,
                        drawables);
                if (drawables.size() > 0) {

                    gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);
                }

                if (drawables.size() == 1) {
                    leftArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    rightArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                gallery.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private List<Drawable> createDrawables(ArrayList<ProductDetails> result) {

            List<Drawable> drawablesUrl = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
            try {
                for (ProductDetails objProDetails : result) {
                    drawablesUrl.add(Global.getBitmapFromURL(
                            ProductsDetailActivity.this,
                            objProDetails.image_path));
                    // drawablesUrl.add(loadImageFromURL(objProDetails.image_path));
                }
                return drawablesUrl;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                return null;
            }

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Drawable loadImageFromURL(String image_path) {
            try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                return d;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noimage);
            }
        }

        private String readJSONSFeed(String url, String productID) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + Constants.REQ_FOR_PRODUCT_IMAGE
                    + productID + Constants.REQ_FOR_OFFER);

            httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpGet.setHeader("password", "password");
            httpGet.setHeader("username", "user");

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                int statuscode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                if (statuscode == 200) {

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line = null;
                    if ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                    }
                    // buffer.close();
                    inputStream.close();

                } else {

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private synchronized ArrayList<ProductDetails> processProductDetailsJSON(
                String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray Records = json
                        .getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_OBJECT_DATA);

                for (int i = 0; i < Records.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Record = Records.getJSONObject(i);

                    String tTitle = Record.getString("title");
                    String tImagePath = Record.getString("image_path");
                    String tDescription = Record.getString("description");
                    tImagePath = Constants.REQ_IMAGE_PRODUCT + tImagePath;
                    pDetails = new ProductDetails(tDescription, tTitle,
                            tImagePath);

                    if (pDetails == null) {

                    } else {
                        productList.add(pDetails);

                    }
                }


            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
                return null;
            }

            return productList;
        }

    }
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity context;

    ImageView imageView;
    private List<Drawable> totalImages;
    private static ViewHolder holder;

    ArrayList<Object> imageGallery;
    int width;
    int height;
    Display display;
    int[] images = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, List<Drawable> drawables) {
        this.context = (Activity) c;
        imageGallery = new ArrayList<Object>();
        this.totalImages = drawables;
        display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        // this.imageGallery = objects;
//      width = display.getWidth();
//      height = display.getHeight();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return totalImages.size();
        // return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                imageView = new ImageView(this.context);
                convertView = imageView;
                holder.imageView = imageView;
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(totalImages.get(position));


            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);





            return imageView;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return imageView;
        }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder() {

        }

        ImageView imageView;
    }


}

Here is my CustomArrayAdapter
CustomArrayAdapter.java

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Products> product;
    int layoutId;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Products> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.layoutId = textViewResourceId;

        this.product = objects;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context, R.drawable.noimage);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        holder.setValues(product.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return product.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvProductTitle;
        TextView tvProductDescription;
        ImageView ivProductLogo, imgArrow;

        public ProgressBar progress;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            tvProductTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvProductDescription = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptions);
            ivProductLogo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivLogoProduct);
            imgArrow = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgArrow);
            progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        }

        public void setValues(Products products) {

            tvProductTitle.setText(products.title);
            tvProductDescription.setText(products.short_description);

            // imageLoader.displayImage(products.image, imageView, options);

            try {
                ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext);

                DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                        .cacheOnDisc().build();
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(products.image, ivProductLogo);

                if (Global.fromProduct) {

                    imgArrow.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_arrow_right));
                } else {
                    imgArrow.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info_btn));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // try {

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

            if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
                String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
                if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
                    bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
                } else {
                    // The same URL is already being downloaded.
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
            if (imageView != null) {
                Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                if (drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable) {
                    DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadedDrawable) drawable;
                    return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloaderTask();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}'
```

Comment: you need to display images from internet and when you scroll should display a spinner before loading image?

Comment: yes exactly i want like that.

Comment: check the below answer.

Comment: try the below and inform

Comment: Thank you @Raghunandan, modifying such code, it worked according to what i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Universal Image Loader from https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.

Add the jar file to your libs folder of your project

Note: The below display's image by downloading images from internet. You can also provide path of images from your sdcard folder.

Universal Image Loader is a improves version of Lazy Loading. Loads Images asynchronously. You can cache images in your sdcard or phone memory if your are downloading image from internet

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/PhoneImageGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivv"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"

    />
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.java

```
    public class AndroidCustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private String[] mStrings={
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/681537837/SmallAvatarx150_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/63737974/2008-11-06_1637_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/612232882/nexusoneavatar_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/213722080/Bugdroid-phone_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/645523828/OT_icon_090918_android_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/681537837/SmallAvatarx150_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/63737974/2008-11-06_1637_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/612232882/nexusoneavatar_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/213722080/Bugdroid-phone_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/645523828/OT_icon_090918_android.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png"
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);


}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
       DisplayImageOptions options;
    public ImageAdapter() {

         //Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
           imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
         // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this)
                      // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
                     .discCacheExtraOptions(1024, 1024, CompressFormat.PNG, 100)
                   // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
                     .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
                     .enableLogging()
                     .build();
            imageLoader.init(config);
         options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .build();
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mStrings.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.rowimage, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivv);
            holder.pb = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pb);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        display(holder.imageview, mStrings[position].toString(), holder.pb);
       // imageLoader.displayImage(data.get(position).toString(), holder.imageview,options);
        return convertView;
    }
     public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
        {
            imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                 spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                 spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                 spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

        });
        }

}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    ProgressBar pb; 

}
}
```

Comment: Images links used above is for  testing and images may be repeated. remember to add internet permission in manifest

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use thread for that which look like following:

```
    logoImageView.setImageDrawable(R.id.drawable.company_logo);
    Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for a second (1000 ms)
    nameImageView.setImageDrawable(R.id.drawable.company_name);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    sloganImageView.setImageDrawable(R.id.drawable.company_slogan);
```

its just for example to understand you.